# SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS query shows columns twice if using REMARKS

Tags: select, db2, system-tables

I've noticed a strange behaviour while working with DB2 and the `SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS` which only appears in one table.

This is my query:

```
select distinct NAME, COLTYPE, LENGTH, SCALE, REMARKS from SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS where  TBNAME='Table1';
```

Normally the result shows every table once.

```
|===================================|
| NAME |COLTYPE|LENGTH|SCALE|REMARKS|
|col1  | ..... |......|.....|.......|
|col2  | ..... |......|.....|.......|
|col3  | ..... |......|.....|.......|
|===================================|
```

But if I use one specific table, let's call it `Table2`, every column shows up twice:

```
|===================================|
| NAME |COLTYPE|LENGTH|SCALE|REMARKS|
|col1  | ..... |......|.....|.......|
|col1  | ..... |......|.....|.......|
|col2  | ..... |......|.....|.......|
|col2  | ..... |......|.....|.......|
|col3  | ..... |......|.....|.......|
|col3  | ..... |......|.....|.......|
|===================================|
```

But only if I include the `REMARKS` in the select-statement. If I remove the `REMARKS` from my select, everything works as expected.

What could be the cause of that problem? Is there something wrong with my query?

Comment: what platform and version of DB2?

Comment: Mainframe and Version 10.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not considered schemas. There could be table2 in schema A and schema B.

IN LUW:

Personally, I recommend the syscat schema in order to query the catalog. The sysibm are internal to DB2 and these tables could change between versions.

```
select TABSCHEMA, TABNAME, COLNAME, TYPENAME, LENGTH, SCALEREMARKS
from syscat.columns
where tabname = 'TABLE2'
```

Answer (score 1):

What's in the remarks column for each row?

You've got a `DISTINCT` in your original query.  Since you're only selecting on table name, is it possible that you have the same table in multiple schema's; one with a remarks and one without?